# How can I write a subquery in Pig Latin?

Tags: apache-pig

I have two data files:

**range.txt**

```
Min Max  Name
1    10    a
11   20    b
21   30    c
31   100   d
101  200   e
```

and **data.txt**

```
1
3
40
150
```

The result I want is:

```
1   a  ( because 1   <= 1   <= 10 )
3   a  ( because 1   <= 3   <= 10 ) 
40  d  ( because 31  <= 40  <= 100 )
150 e  ( because 101 <= 150 <= 200 )
```

How do I write the Pig Script?

I tried:

```
MyREPO = LOAD '/repos/range.txt'  USING PigStorage(',') AS (start:long,end:long,location:chararray);

MyDATA = LOAD '/repos/data.txt' AS (col1:long);


B = FOREACH MyDATA {

    C = FILTER MyREPO BY ( MyDATA.col1 >= start  AND MyDATA.col1 <= end  );

    GENERATE MyDATA.col1,C.location;
}


STORE C into '/result/'  USING PigStorage();
```

the above script does not compile with pig.
but it show what I want to do.

### thanks.

maybe this way pass through?

make start and end in range.txt a concrated string,
make col1 in data.txt a single string,
I write a custom ComparisonFunc,in this function,
split the string into start and end ,and test if col1 is in this range?

BUT HOW TO?
this is my second day on PIG......

Comment: key in range.txt is [begin,end],and key in data.txt is col1,relations between two keys is not the 'equality join;but one key in the range of the other,I donot konw how to join them.

Answer (score 1):

this is another possible solution:

```
myRepo = LOAD 'range.txt'  USING PigStorage(',') AS (start:long,end:long,location:chararray);
myData = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (col1:long);

myRepoData = cross myRepo, myData;
myRepoData2 = filter myRepoData by col1 >= start and col1 <= end;
myRepoData3 = foreach myRepoData2 generate col1, location;

dump myRepoData3;
```

Answer (score 0):

One very naive way would be to bloat data from range.txt.

`range = LOAD 'range.txt' AS (min:long, max:long, name:chararray);

    m = FOREACH range GENERATE FLATTEN(udf(min, max, name));

    data = LOAD 'data.txt' AS NUMBER:long;

    output = JOIN m BY $0, data by NUMBER;

    dump output;`

Output key,value pairs starting from min to max with key as the number and value is 'name'.
So 1 10 a would be 1 a, 2 a, 3 a etc.
Make sure the udf returns a databag so that flatten would give you one entry per line.

Not super efficient, but this could be a starting point.